# Error 'IConfigurationProvider' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I updated my ASP.NET 5 project from Beta 7 to Beta 8 and I am getting the following error message.

```
Error CS7069: Reference to type 'IConfigurationProvider' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions', but it could not be found
```

Any idea what has changed? Below is the I am using.

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        this.Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder() <-- ERROR
            .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the answer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173372/asp-net5-startup-cs-configurationbuilder

Comment: I did try that. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added next dependencies in my project.json:

```
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8"
```

and changed code of creating ConfigurationBuilder in Startup.cs to:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
    .AddJsonFile("config.json")
    .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
```

In my case it works

Answer (score 1):

The `ConfigurationBuilder` reference has been moved out of `Microsoft.Configuration.Abstractions` in beta8 and is now locoated in `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions`.

Update any namespace (using) statements which reference `Microsoft.Configuration.Abstractions` to `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions` in your Startup.cs file and verify that it is listed in your dependencies in project.json.